# How to change default strategy for project version?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, netflix, netflix-nebula-plugins

I need my artifact to be built with `project.version` equals to snapshot git based version.

For example, default version after `clean build` or idea build:
`0.2-dev.#hash`

I need: `1.1-SNAPSHOT` where 1.1 is from git tag, like when I run `snapshot` task

I tried to change [ReleasePluginExtension.groovy](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-release-plugin/blob/9050b9719e494778c3b6d129bcbdc6a1c92b7648/src/main/groovy/nebula/plugin/release/git/base/ReleasePluginExtension.groovy):

```
release {
    defaultVersionStrategy = Strategies.SNAPSHOT
}
```

And

```
release {
    versionStrategy(Strategies.SNAPSHOT)
}
```

Doesn't work

My current workaround to set project.version inside by build.gradle like in library code - create object of snapshot strategy and call #version() method:

```
release {
    def gitRoot = project.hasProperty('git.root') ? project.property('git.root') : project.rootProject.projectDir
    def git = Grgit.open(dir: gitRoot)
    project.version = Strategies.SNAPSHOT.infer(project, git).version()
}
```

But i think it should be customizable by nebula-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's been solved. Similar setting works for us with `version "15.0.2"`, but it has to follow the `plugins` block directly:

```
release {
  defaultVersionStrategy = nebula.plugin.release.git.opinion.Strategies.SNAPSHOT
}
```

Latest working combination:

- nebula.release 16.0.0
- gradle 7.3.3
- springboot 2.7.0

Not working anymore with gradle 7.4+